# Hide search bar when back button is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have encountered a problem that is my search bar doesn't hide when I tap back navigation button.

In fact, isMovingFromViewController doesn't respond when search bar is active.

I would like to know when back button is tapped so that I could make the search bar inactive and hide the keyboard.

Have you ever seen this error before?

If so, please let me know how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: I like to use `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: @Don it works thank you but I don't understand why haha thank you anyway

Comment: `viewDidDisappear` is a normal lifecycle event, along with your `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, etc. It's called automatically for you so that you can perform actions at certain stages. When you tap the back button, `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` will be called. When overriding these methods, always call `super` first. For this example, `super.viewDidDisappear(animated)`.

Comment: @Don ok but just one thing, the search bar is disappearing only after back button is touched, and that it quite ugly to see. Do you know how to hide it before ?

Comment: See if `viewWillDisappear` looks better. Put your `endEditing` and `searchController.isActive = false` calls in there. I guess I normally use `viewDidDisappear` when moving forward, and `viewWillDisappear` when going back.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, you can also implement a custom back button, do whatever you need to do and then dismiss.

Comment: @Don it's alright I think that it's just that inactivating search bar takes quite long but it's ok thank you

Answer (score 0):

Some code would have been helpful, anyway to hide a view after a click add add a function to the button then call viewName.isHidden. but i cant suggest more until i see a code or at least a screen